# Ignoring color palette in 'scale_color_distiller'

Tags: r

Using the code below I am getting a Feature plot for particular gene from a scRNA-Seq dataset in Seurat in R.

```
FeaturePlot(
  seurat.obj.scaled,
  features = "NRP1",
  split.by = 'sample_status',
  raster = FALSE
)
```

[image: Feature Plot]

I want this color palette to remain but I also want to add the color gradient bar on the right bottom side of the image as I obtain from the code below-

```
FeaturePlot(
  seurat.obj.scaled,
  features = "NRP1",
  split.by = 'sample_status',
  raster = FALSE
)  &
  scale_color_distiller(name = stringr::str_wrap("Expression Level"), 
                        guide = guide_colourbar(title.position = "right")) &
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9,0.2),legend.title = element_text(angle = 90, size = 8 ,vjust = .1, hjust = .5),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"))
```

[image: Feature Plot with changing color]

As it is evident, the color palette changes when I input the extra few lines of code. I do not understand which part of the `scale_color_distiller` or `theme` function changes the color palette. I need the color palette as the first picture but I want the legend (color bar and vertical "Expression level") as shown in the second plot.

Comment: which version of Seurat are you using? FeaturePlot includes the legend by default in Seuratv4

Comment: about `scale_color_distiller`, it has an argument called palette with default value of 1 - this is what changes the color scheme

Comment: @M.G. I am using Seurat version 4.3.0.1. Regarding the 'palette' argument, 1 is default and -1 gives you reverse color palette. I tried 0, thinking it might turn off the palette, but it did not.